# Cannot get rid of some space in multiplot using base R and maps

Tags: r

I am trying to remove the space between the top and bottom plots, but cannot find the parameters that I need to modify. I tried a few different things and thought I found my problem with map resetting the par(mar) parameters e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168721/drawing-maps-without-margins-in-r), but this is not it!

See Figure:

[image: multimaps]

Any idea. I want to have all these maps together (no space between the top 3 and 2 below), but would like to have only the bottom left map showing axes.

My code:

```
    library(mapdata)#for "worldHires"
    library(maps)
    op<-par(mfcol=c(2,3),oma=c(0,2,0,0),mar=c(2,2,0,0))

for (j in 1:5){
    map("worldHires", fill=T,xlim=c(-70,-55),ylim=c(66,71),col=c(gray(0.8),gray(0.6)),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
      if (j==2){
        map.axes()
      }
      else{
    box(col = "black")
      }
     text(-56,66.5,paste(j),font=2,cex=1.5)
    }
par(op)
```

Comment: I don't have the mapdata package installed, but `par(mar = c(2,2,2,1))` or something similar would put you in the right direction methinks

Comment: Thanks @rawr, I fixed the library. You need to install mapdata to be able to use "worldHires". Fixing mar does not fix my issue.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the `mai` parameter of `par`? It might help.

Comment: Have you looked into setting this up using layout()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is one way of fixing some of the white gap between the top and bottom maps using layout as suggested by @miles2know. However, it is not exactly what I was hoping for i.e., no more space between all maps! Any help on this would be much appreciated.

```
library(maptools)
library(maps)

mat<-matrix(c(1:6),2,3,byrow=T)
matly<-layout(mat,respect=T)
layout.show(matly)

# jpeg("maps2.jpeg")
layout(mat,respect=T)
op<-par(mar=c(0,0,0,0), mgp=c(0,1,0),oma=c(0.5,2,0,0))#mgp:affect the margin line for the axis
for (j in 1:5){
map("worldHires", fill=T,xlim=c(-70,-55),ylim=c(66,71),col=c(gray(0.8),gray(0.6)),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  if (j==4){
    map.axes()
  }
  else{
box(col = "black")
  }
 text(-56,66.5,paste(j),font=2,cex=1.5)
}
par(op)
# dev.off()
```

New plot[image]